# What are the general in-scope and out-of-scope guidelines?

Tags: discussion

As the community forms, it is important to define a specific set of guidelines for what is in-scope and what is out-of-scope for questions.

Answer (score 11):

Let's see what sorts of questions get asked and then - when there are concerns regarding a topic - start specific discussions regarding them.

Tag them [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) and let folks present their arguments for and against including the question on the site. These can then serve as a guide for the folks answering, reviewing and closing questions, as well as the basis for future on/off-topic guidance in the help system.